# Is the visited link color too close to the default text color for posts and comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, css, user-interface

In posts and comments, the visited link color is `#223e6b`, while the text color is `#444444` (or at least that what it looks like when I use Digital Colormeter). I have a hard time distinguishing links and text at that color unless I hover over the links. It seems like the site needs a more distinct link color. I don't have a color suggestion, I just think for accessibility and usability the color contrast, or some other method could be used to help make visited links more visible.

Comment: +1 I agree completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been changed to be lighter by Jin.